# Call function template overload for derived variadic class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a variadic class template `deriv` which derives off variadic class template `base`.

I have a function template which takes any type `T`, and an overload for `base<Ts...>` types;

How can I get the `base<Ts...>` overload to be used when passing a `const deriv<Ts...>&`?

**Working example below:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Ts>
struct base
{
    std::tuple<Ts...> tuple;
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct deriv : base<Ts...>
{
};

//--------------------------------

template<typename T>
void func(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "T" << std::endl;
}

template<typename... Ts>
void func(const base<Ts...>&)
{
    std::cout << "base<Ts...>" << std::endl;
}

//----------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int a;
    base <int, double> b;
    deriv<int, double> c;

    func(a);
    func(b);
    func(c); // <--- I want func<base<Ts...>> not func<T> to be called here

    exit(0);
}
```

**Output from exemplar:**

```
T
base<Ts...>
T
```

**What I want the output to be:**

```
T
base<Ts...>
base<Ts...>
```

Comment: Interesting question, I spent a few minutes fiddling about and unfortunately nothing came of it. Hopefully a better programmer than me can answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Unless* you are ready to re-engineer your code, **you cannot**, and for a good reason.

Your non-variadic overload of `func()` is a *better match* than the variadic version: in fact, when attempting to resolve your function call, the type parameter `T` for the non-variadic overload will be deduced to be `derived<int, double>`.

On the other hand, the parameter pack `Ts` in your variadic overload will be deduced to be `int, double`. After type deduction, this will practically leave the compiler with these two choices for resolving your call:

```
void func(const deriv<int, double>&); // Non-variadic after type deduction
void func(const base<int, double>&);    // Variadic after type deduction
```

Which one should be picked when trying to match a call whose argument is of type `derived<int, double>`?

```
deriv<int, double> c;
func(c);
```

Obviously, the first, non variadic overload is a **better match**.

So how do you get the *second* overload called instead of the first? You have a few choices. First of all, you can qualify your call by explicitly specifying the template arguments:

```
func<int, double>(c);
```

If you do not like that, maybe you can re-think the definition of the non-variadic overload of `func()`: do you really want it to accept *any* possible type `T`? Or are there some types for which you know this overload is not to be invoked? If so, you can use SFINAE techniques and `std::enable_if` to rule out the undesired matches.

As a further possibility, you can relax a bit the signature of your template function and allow deducing its argument as an instantiation of a certain template class:

```
template<template<typename...> class T, typename... Ts>
void func(const T<Ts...>&)
{
    std::cout << "base<Ts...>" << std::endl;
}
```

This change alone should fix your program's behavior in the way you want.

**UPDATE:**

If you want your specialized function template to be invoked **only** for classes derived from any instance of the `base<>` class template, you can use the `std::is_base_of<>` type trait and `std::enable_if` in the following way:

```
template<template<typename...> class T, typename... Ts>
void func(
    const T<Ts...>&, 
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<base<Ts...>, T<Ts...>>::value
        >::type* = nullptr
    )
{
    std::cout << "base<Ts...>" << std::endl;
}
```

**ADDENDUM:**

In those situations where template function overloading won't help with your design, notice that you can always resort to **partial template specialization**. Unfortunately, function templates cannot be specialized, but you can still exploit *class* template partial specialization and add a helper function to hide the instantiation of that template. This is how you would rewrite your code:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T>
    struct X
    {
        static void func(const T&)
        {
            std::cout << "T" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    template<template<typename...> class T, typename... Ts>
    struct X<T<Ts...>>
    {
        static void func(const T<Ts...>&)
        {
            std::cout << "base<Ts...>" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}

template<typename T>
void func(const T& t)
{
    details::X<T>::func(t);
}
```

Comment: I found your well written answer intuitive and wanted to thank you for the time you spent.

Comment: @Iori: actually there is one more solution I am going to write, hold on a second please.

Comment: @AndyProwl - is it possible for the second `struct X` to only match `base<Ts...>` objects and `base<Ts...>` derived objects? ie: It should fail to capture if I pass a `std::tuple<Ts...>` (which it does accept at the moment)

Comment: @Iori: there you go, I updated my answer - actually, I was not suggesting you to un-accept it :-D

Comment: @Iori: yes, it is possible, by using some SFINAE machinery and the `std::is_base_of` traits. However, that's going to get a bit more complicated.

Comment: +1, I didn't know you could use `typename...` with template template arguments.

Comment: @Iori: I added the version for detecting only subclasses of `base<Ts...>`. Do you think you can you re-accept the question now? ;-)

Comment: @AndyProwl - thanks - as suggested, a combination of `enable_if` and `is_base_of` has done the trick. I changed the first `struct X` to `template<typename T, class Enable=void> struct X`; and the second to `struct X<T<Ts...>, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<base<Ts...>,T<Ts...>>::value>::type>`

Comment: @AndyProwl - do you mind if I edit your answer to add the `enable_if` magic sauce?

Comment: @Iori: not at all, go on, but I think I added one version using `std::enable_if` as well under the "UPDATE" section, so I suggest putting it there as an alternative solution. Anyway feel free to edit

Comment: @AndyProwl Ah sorry - missed that part! :)

Answer (score 0):

The generic-template overload is a better match, since it requires no conversion (except adding `const`, which both overloads have).

You can get the `base`-template overload by adding an explicit cast ([example](http://ideone.com/53E01O)):

```
func(static_cast<base<int, double> &>(c));
```

(Alternatively, you could forgo the multiple overloads and instead stick some `is_base_of` helper logic into your main function template's body.)

Comment: The call to `func` is inside another function template, so I don't know the type of `c` at this point. I therefore need the template instantiation to work implicitly.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: You add a parameter pack to the template. I'm going to show that in a minute, please hold on

Comment: @AndyProwl yes, I just saw your answer, I didn't know it was possible :)